# Is there any available Strava statistics regarding rider's distance compared to others' per year?

Tags: strava, statistics

I'm writing an application and would like to know how my logged 22.000 km during 2017 stand compared to all Swedish Strava users.

https://2017.strava.com/en-us/videos/64f479a9bec7cd1793afe4322823092b99d462bf/

Comment: I think off-topic here. Have you tried Strava Developers groups or help resources?

Comment: I too think it's off-topic.  But have a look at Strava apps, particularly the ["Social Motivation" section](https://www.strava.com/apps/social-motivation)

Comment: Not about bicycles or riding per-se

Comment: For me Strava is very much about bicycling and my life in the saddle. Didn't know you guys thought otherwise. There was a Strava tag in use here as well.

Comment: Tried to find a Strava user forum, but was met with this: https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208845497-Create-a-forum-for-communication-between-members

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is overly restricted to a very specific situation. Why only Sweden? Why only Strava? Are we going to have a question for every combination of country and ride-logging software? Developing software is not cycling.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.marcellobrivio.com/projects/strava-toolbox/?logout=1

This online app will let you connect to your Strava account and compare pretty much anything you want. It allows you to see some fairly interesting comparisons. You’ll want to connect your account and then scroll to “Strava Distance Ranking”. I’m not sure if there’s an option to narrow your search from “Worldwide” to “Sweden”, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: You are completely correct - welcome to SE and thank you for your answer.  Do have a browse through the [tour] for completion.

Comment: Thanks. As you said, not per country, but much worse, not even per year...